# How can I perform partial string matching in Excel, allowing for unordered strings that are not in proper sequence?

Tags: excel, fuzzywuzzy

I have two tables in Excel. The first table contains a list of stock names in the correct order. However, in the second table, the stock names are not in the correct order and may be partially correct or mismatched when compared to the first table.

I would like to use the VLOOKUP function to match the stock names from the first table with the corresponding stock names in the second table. Then, I want to retrieve the stock prices from the second table and display them in a third table, matching the order of the stock names in the first table.

**Table : 1**

| stock |
| --- |
| Amara Raja Batteries |
| Caplin Point Laboratories |
| E I D-Parry |
| Gujarat State Petronet |
| Happiest Minds Technologies |
| KPIT Technologies |
| MTAR Technologies |
| Paras Defence and Space Technologies |
| Polyplex Corp |
| Praj Industries |
| Sona Blw |
| Tata cor |
| hdfc |

**Table : 2**

| stock | price |
| --- | --- |
| Amara Batteries | 23 |
| Caplin Point lab | 91 |
| Defence and Space | 159 |
| E I D-Parry (India) | 227 |
| Happiest Minds Technologies | 295 |
| KPIT Tech | 363 |
| MTAR Technologies | 431 |
| Polyplex Corp | 499 |
| Praj Industries | 567 |
| Tata Power cor | 771 |
| Sona Blw Forgings | 635 |
| State Petronet | 703 |

**Table : 1 after retrieving price** This is expected Output table which I want to achieved

| stock | Expected Result |
| --- | --- |
| Amara Raja Batteries | 23 |
| Caplin Point Laboratories | 91 |
| E I D-Parry | 227 |
| Gujarat State Petronet | 703 |
| Happiest Minds Technologies | 295 |
| KPIT Technologies | 363 |
| MTAR Technologies | 431 |
| Paras Defence and Space Technologies | 159 |
| Polyplex Corp | 499 |
| Praj Industries | 567 |
| Sona Blw | 635 |
| Tata cor | 771 |
| hdfc | #N/A |

Comment: Try using `Power Query` using `Fuzzy` matching.